# Javascript: How cut out part of an integer?

Tags: javascript, integer, position

## How to cut out part of an integer?

---

*What can i do to get an integer*  `12`  *or* `123` *from a variable* `n`

```js
let n = 123456;
```

Comment: what is the condition here? need to cut off all the occurences of `12` or `123`?

Comment: What is the logic of getting that part. Do you provide length to function `2` and `3` for  `12` and `123` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to just cast the input number to a string, and then take a substring:

```js
var n = 123456;
n = n + "";
var output = n.slice(0, 2);
console.log(output);
```

Another approach, if all you want is to get some number of leading digits, would be to divide by the correct multiple of ten, e.g.

```
var n = 123456;
var output = Math.floor(output / 10000);
```

Comment: Wait...it actually has a _demo_ :P

Comment: We still do not know what the OP's required condition is

Comment: @MaheerAli You're right, I changed my answer.  JavaScript is not my native language (it is English).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you - you first change it to string and split it to an array and then remove the unwanted characters, then join the array together, and parse it as an integer: (edited to reflect @VLAZ's comment.

```
parseInt(n.toString().slice(0,2)));
```

Comment: You are correct, missed that one. Thank you - I already edited it.

Answer (score 2):

The strategy I suggest is to convert the integer value to a string which you may manipulate with parseInt() as well as the string's substr() method, as follows:

```js
const START       = 0;
const first_two   = 2;
const first_three = 3;
const base_ten    = 10;

let n = 123456;
let res = parseInt( String( n ).substr( START,first_two ),base_ten );
console.log(res);
res = parseInt(String( n ).substr( START,first_three ),base_ten );
console.log(res);
```

The Number Object has a toString() method but apparently it is safer to convert the integer to a string by passing the integer value of **n** to the String Object per this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5m2e8j/string_vs_tostring/).  You may then use the String Object's substr() method to access the first two or three digits appearing in the string. Next, you may take the resulting numeric string and pass it to [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), along with a base parameter to obtain the integer value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!